# WSO2 API Manager with HMAC Authentication

Tags: wso2

Does anyone know how to add HMAC based authentication for WSO2 API Manager?

Background - We're rolling out WSO2 API Manager 1.3 in front of our publicly available web services and we need JavaScript applications (once authenticated) to be able to consume the services directly (not via a service proxy on their server to handle the OAuth authentication).

Does anyone know the easiest way to get this implemented in WSO2?  We've started implementing an AbstractHandler and Authenticator but this seems overkill - someone must have done this or have some pointers on this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own handler which can implement the `AbstractHandler`. 
Signature verification can be implemented as an API handler similar to the 'APIAuthenticationHandler'. The access token that was provided earlier can be used as  the Mac Identifier. The consumer secret can be used as the Mac key, which is a shared secret between the consumer and the provider used to sign the normalized request string.

Comment: Thanks @Ratha, this is the path we have currently taken, I guess it's just a little disappointing to not have a major authentication mechanism such as HMAC supported out of the box but I guess the product is young also.  Whenever custom coding security it's a risky situation that bugs will introduce security holes.

Comment: Thanks..mike we will consider HMAC auth in our future roadmap

Comment: Thanks @Ratha, at least an easier way to implement would be appreciated.  As noted, if APIs are being consumed directly by JavaScript applications, which is very common, then this is really required ASAP as Layer 7 as some others already support this.

Comment: @MikeStokes here is a detail blog on this with steps and sample code http://nallaa.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/signature-verification-with-wso2-api-manager/

Comment: Thanks @Ratha for that link, it looks like what we need, we will implement and report back findings for everyone

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will help you but we needed our password hashes to be in PBKDF2. So I extended the JDBCUserStoreManager overriding only the preparePassword method. Inside it changed from MessageDigest to SecretKeyFactory for the PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 algorithm. You can use Mac i guess?

Comment: Thanks @kmkale, not exactly what we need but something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by implementing a custom mediator and engaging it to the in-flow sequence. The API exposed by API Manager would be OAuth protected, but the actual backend would be HMAC protected. You can find more information on this in the article [1].

[1] https://wso2.com/library/article/2017/10/integrating-wso2-api-manager-with-a-hmac-secured-backend/